# How can I execute an operator immediately whenever any operator in front of a specific operator fails?

Tags: python, airflow

I am kinda new to apache airflow and wanted to do some bashoperators.

Ideally, the dag runs like t1 >> t2 >> ... >> t9 >> t10, right?

But what I want is that if the event before t9 fails, it will then execute t9 and t10 immediately.

Here's what I had tried:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator

from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='vp_bash_dag',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='None',
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    tags=['vp', 'example'],
    params={"example_key": "example_value"},
) as dag:

    t01 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t01',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/1 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t02 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t02',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/2 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t03 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t03',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/3 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t04 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t04',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/4 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t05 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t05',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/5 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t06 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t06',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/6 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t07 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t07',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/7 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t08 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t08',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/8 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t09 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t09',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/9 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
    dag=dag)

    t10 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t10',
    bash_command='echo done',
    dag=dag)

t01 >> t02 >> t03 >> t04 >> t05 >> t06 >> t07 >> t08 >> t09 >> t10
```

Is there anyone can guide me maybe with some keywords or hints?

update

the result like this what I wanted.

It may not look or sound like what I said.

But the result is what I had expected.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='vp_failed_branch',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    tags=['vp', 'example'],
    params={"example_key": "example_value"},
) as dag:

    t01 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t01',
    bash_command='echo runed >> /tmp/airflow/01.runed',
    dag=dag)

    t02 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t02',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/2 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t03 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t03',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/3 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t04 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t04',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/4 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t05 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t05',
    bash_command='[ -f /tmp/5 ] && exit 0 || exit 1',
    dag=dag)

    t06 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t06',
    bash_command='echo runed >> /tmp/airflow/06.runed',
    dag=dag)

    t07 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t07',
    bash_command='echo runed >> /tmp/airflow/07.runed',
    dag=dag)

    t08 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t08',
    bash_command='echo runed >> /tmp/airflow/08.runed',
    dag=dag)

    t09 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t09',
    bash_command='echo runed >> /tmp/airflow/09.runed',
    dag=dag)

    t10 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t10',
    bash_command='echo runed >> /tmp/airflow/10.runed',
    dag=dag)

    t09_f = BashOperator(
    task_id='t09_f',
    bash_command='echo runed >> /tmp/airflow/09_f.runed',
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
    dag=dag)

    t10_f = BashOperator(
    task_id='t10_f',
    bash_command='echo runed >> /tmp/airflow/10_f.runed',
    dag=dag)


t01 >> t02 >> t03 >> t04 >> t05 >> t06 >> t07 >> t08 >> t09 >> t10
t01 >> t09_f
t02 >> t09_f
t03 >> t09_f
t04 >> t09_f
t05 >> t09_f
t06 >> t09_f
t07 >> t09_f
t08 >> t09_f
t09_f >> t10_f
```

Comment: You want to trigger `t09` and `t10` in parallel if `t08` fails? that's what you are looking for?

Comment: I mean, if I executed t01 and it failed, it will jump to t09 and after t09 is done, it will jump to t10 like usual.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `chain`:

```
from airflow.utils.helpers import chain
chain([t01,t02,t03,t04,t05,t06,t07, t08], t09, t10)
```

Note in Airflow>=2.0 the path is:

```
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain
```

The dependencies will be:

[image]

Since `t09` has `TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED` it will run as soon one of `[t01,t02,t03,t04,t05,t06,t07, t08]` will fail.

Comment: it's nearly what I wanted, do you think if the dag can be skip to a specific dag if the dag in front of it fails?

like this:
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4(failed) -> 9(skipping 5 to 8) -> 10

Comment: I dont understand your description.  Please add inage showing the dependency you want to set

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided initially worked for me (i.e. simply adding a `trigger_rule` for `t09` as `TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED`).  See screenshot links below.  Running on Airflow 2.0.

[Task `t01` fails and `t09` executes followed by `t10`.  DAG succeeded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMIbA.png)

What behavior were you seeing with the original code?

Full code for reference (slightly changed from bash commands):

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

from datetime import timedelta

args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="vp_failed_branch",
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    tags=["vp", "example"],
    params={"example_key": "example_value"},
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    t01 = BashOperator(task_id="t01", bash_command="exit 1")

    t02 = BashOperator(task_id="t02", bash_command="[ -f /tmp/2 ] && exit 0 || exit 1")

    t03 = BashOperator(task_id="t03", bash_command="[ -f /tmp/3 ] && exit 0 || exit 1")

    t04 = BashOperator(task_id="t04", bash_command="[ -f /tmp/4 ] && exit 0 || exit 1")

    t05 = BashOperator(task_id="t05", bash_command="[ -f /tmp/5 ] && exit 0 || exit 1")

    t06 = BashOperator(
        task_id="t06", bash_command="echo runed >> /tmp/airflow/06.runed"
    )

    t07 = BashOperator(
        task_id="t07", bash_command="echo runed >> /tmp/airflow/07.runed"
    )

    t08 = BashOperator(
        task_id="t08", bash_command="echo runed >> /tmp/airflow/08.runed"
    )

    t09 = BashOperator(
        task_id="t09",
        bash_command="echo foo",
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
    )

    t10 = BashOperator(task_id="t10", bash_command="echo bar")

    t01 >> t02 >> t03 >> t04 >> t05 >> t06 >> t07 >> t08 >> t09 >> t10
```